# Can you run an AWS Lambda using Greengrass as part of your Mobile App?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, mobile, aws-lambda

We have an application that normally communicates with our AWS backend that triggers some Lambdas to process some cloud data and generate some result. This works great however, our application needs to be able to run in an offline mode. I know that AWS Greengrass can let you execute your Lambda code locally for an IoT device. What I want to know is, is it possible to leverage greengrass this way from a Mobile app? Specifically iOS but I would be curious if this would work for android as well. Is there anything that would prevent me from leveraging the AWS greengrass stuff from inside my mobile application?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Casually I worked quite a lot with both iOS and Greengrass but I’ve never heard about a GG daemon that could run on iOS. But even if there was one your app would most likely violate the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/), specifically the 2.5.2 point that prohibits downloading source code from external resources except in some special cases. So you wouldn’t be able to publish your app anyway.